# How can I dynamically access a method from other service in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I've just started to learn ts. I'm getting type name from request in controller. It might be, for example, "follow" or "check_follow". And I want dynamically access appropriate method from follow_service.ts class. How can I do that? Currently I'm trying to do so like this:

```
this.followService[req.body.opeationType](author_id, fan_id);
```

But typescript is yelling at me:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'PaymentService'.
```

What should I do? Thank you!

Follow service looks like:

```
class FollowService {

public async follow(author_id: string, fan_id: string): Promise<any> {
    ///
  }
public async follow(author_id: string, fan_id: string): Promise<any> {
    ///
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing `follow_service.ts` but it seems `req.body.opeationType` has the type `any`. Maybe try to cast it to `string` (if it is a string of cource) like `this.followService[req.body.opeationType as string](author_id, fan_id);`?

Comment: Please, provide more information.

Comment: @DorinBaba, what kind of information do you need?

Comment: `req.body.opeationType` is a string representing the desired method's name, right? like `follow`. If you call the method hard coding the type, like `this.followService['follow'](author_id, fan_id)` it works?

Comment: @DorinBaba, yes, if I hardcode method name it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a type for your service you make an assertion that the request gives you a key (of course you probably should make sure that is actually the case as well):

```
this.followService[req.body.opeationType as keyof FollowService](author_id, fan_id);
```

This currently assumes everything in `FollowService` is a function that has the compatible signature accepting two IDs.

The easiest way of getting around these problems is listing the valid keys manually:

```
this.followService[req.body.opeationType as 'follow' | 'check_follow'](author_id, fan_id);
```

Using advanced types you can create the resulting type `'follow' | 'check_follow'` dynamically as well:

```
type FollowServiceFunctions = {
    [K in keyof FollowService]: FollowService[K] extends
        (author_id: string, fan_id: string) => Promise<any> ? K : never
}[keyof FollowService]

// ...

this.followService[req.body.opeationType as FollowServiceFunctions](author_id, fan_id);
```

---

Type declarations for the service would in general look fairly similar to what you listed in the question:

```
declare class FollowService {
    follow(author_id: string, fan_id: string): Promise<any>;
    check_follow(author_id: string, fan_id: string): Promise<any>;
}
```

But depending on how the service is made available, e.g. via a global variable, native module, CommonJS module, etc. the details may vary. Please [see the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), as this can be tricky and is a major part of dealing with TypeScript issues. Getting a good understanding of how these declarations work is recommended.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: Actually how I can add a type for my service? Via interface?

Comment: Yes, though it depends on where that service comes from. If it is a class outside your own code, you should use a [type declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) that uses a `class` as well.

Comment: @gachiKoKa: I added an easy workaround if the automatic key resolution is not helpful.

Comment: Also `opeationType` is probably missing an `r` => `operationType`

Comment: Oh, I'm such a newbie. What does r => operationType mean? Also could you please give me an example how I could implement type declaration in this code? Follow service is outside of my code. Many thanks

Comment: @gachiKoKa: I was just pointing out the missing letter `r` and the right side of the arrow shows the word with the letter inserted.

Comment: @gachiKoKa: Added a note on the type declaration, but you probably will need to familiarize yourself with the documentation. Declaration files can be quite a pain...

Answer (score 0):

If you say that calling the method via `this.followService['follow']` works, then the problem is obvious - `req.body.opeationType` is not a valid string, or it isn't a string in the first palce. I'd suggest you to console.log the `opeationType` and to check it's value, or to try converting it to string, like `opeationType.toString()`, might help.

Also, analyze request's body structure, probably the field is called `operationType`, not `opeationType`